# Python: Searching text for Strings from one List and replacing them with Strings from another

Tags: python, string, list, search

I'm trying to create a program to do *very* simple encryption/compression.

Basically, the program requests input in the form of a sentence which is split into words, e.g.

```
this is the gamma
```

I then have two lists:

```python
mylist1 = ("alpha","beta","gamma","delta")
mylist2 = ("1","2","3","4")
```

Each word is matched against a list which contains a number of words. if the words are present in the list then it should replace the word with the corresponding number in the other list. The output should be:

```
this is the 3
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```python
text = input("type your sentence \n")
words = text.split(" ")

mylist1 = ("alpha","beta","gamma","delta")
mylist2 = ("1","2","3","4")

#I was looking at zipping the lists together but wasn't sure I was on the right track
#ziplist = zip(mylist1, mylist2) 

for word in words:
    if word in mylist1:
    text = text.replace(word,mylist2[])

print (text)
```

[This question that I was looking into yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882448/replacing-a-word-in-a-list-with-a-value-from-a-dict/) shows how to do this using a dictionary but I encountered a problem when trying to convert the text file back from numbers to words again. (I swapped the Keys and Values around. I'm pretty certain I shouldn't do that)

Any input would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the index of word from mylist1 and replace the occurrence of word in the variable text with the element at that same index in mylist2

```
text = text.replace(word, mylist2[mylist1.index(word)])
```

Comment: Index!, doh. I couldn't figure out how to link them. You can tell i'm still learning. You are a bit of a legend. Thanks.