# Replace parts of string that match items from one list with parts of string from another list one by one

Tags: python, string, list, replace

For example, I have a string:

```
string1 = 'a b c d e f g h i j'
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
string1 = 'a_b c_d e_f g_h i_j'
```

by matching the substrings of string1 with items from list1, and then replacing the matched substrings with items from list2 sequentially (e.g. by checking the presence of each item from list1 in string1, and then replacing it with respective list2's item if list1's item is present in the string)?

```
list1 = ['a b', 'c d', 'e f', 'g h', 'i j']
list2 = ['a_b', 'c_d', 'e_f', 'g_h', 'i_j']
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Searching text for Strings from one List and replacing them with Strings from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900015/python-searching-text-for-strings-from-one-list-and-replacing-them-with-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pair up the lists with `zip`, then apply `str.replace` on every pair

```
list1 = ['a b', 'c d', 'e f', 'g h', 'i j']
list2 = ['a_b', 'c_d', 'e_f', 'g_h', 'i_j']
string1 = 'a b c d e f g h i j'

for search_text, replace_text in zip(list1, list2):
    string1 = string1.replace(search_text, replace_text)

# a_b c_d e_f g_h i_j
```